# Visual Studio - What are suggestion and standard completion modes

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio, there's a button on the toolbar with tooltip:

> Toggles between suggestion and standard completion modes. (Ctrl+Alt+Space)

My guess is that these have something to do with IntelliSense, but I'm not sure.

**What is suggestion mode and what is standard completion mode?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference seems to be in whether completion is committed when you type keys that are not explicit commit keystrokes while typing.  <kbd>Tab</kbd> is an explicit commit character; <kbd>.</kbd> and <kbd>;</kbd> are examples of keys that are not explicit commit characters.

If I type `"foo".sub(` (in C# as an example) the behavior will be as follows:

- with the button enabled (suggestion mode), I will get the same literal output with a closing parenthesis added: `"foo".sub()`
- with the button disabled (standard mode), it completes using the best match in the completion list: `"foo".Substring()`

Turning this behavior on is more suitable in languages or projects where you are invoking dynamic (or new, not-yet-existing) methods and properites that are not present in the completion list, so that you don't have to fight with undesired partial matches.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the true purpose of the option: `invoking dynamic (or new, not-yet-existing) methods and properties`