# Visual studio 2022 how to auto complete only on tab?

Tags: c#, autocomplete, visual-studio-2022

Right now, visual studio 2022 will auto complete on a whole bunch of characters that I use in normal coding, such as ( and space.If i for example intend to create the method Generate later but add a call to it in my code, typing Generate( it will be replaced with GenerateDocumentationPage() which is completely irrelevant. So then I have to revert and type my function call again. How can I fix this so that it only complete on tab?

I was hoping to find some setting for this under IntelliCode but it seems like there is no configuration for auto replacement there. How can this be solved?

Comment: I think https://stackoverflow.com/a/55528895/25071 has the info you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

I think I have found the answer in next link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760368/disabling-autocompletion-from-spacebar-in-vs-2022.html

ANSWER: Edit -> IntelliSense -> Switch Between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion or Shortcut CTRL+ALT+SPACE

Best Regards,
Genís

Comment: This has no effect, it still auto completes with space (, ) etc.

Comment: It worked for me. Now only tab accepts intellisense suggestion. return and space function as newline and space character.