# visual studio 2022 auto complete not working like it used to work in 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

hi I installed the new visual studio 2022 and now my auto complete is not working like it used to work in visual studio 2019 even though I imported my old configs.
I am using visual studio togheter with Unity.

When I want to write a new Function like:
public void OnAnim(){
}
when I enter "("
it autocompletes to
public void OnAnimatorIK(int layerIndex) {
}

and I don't want that. But I want to see the sugestions, but I want it only to autocomplete on "enter" oder "tab" and not on "("

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - What are suggestion and standard completion modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55507637/visual-studio-what-are-suggestion-and-standard-completion-modes)

Comment: this does not solve my problem. I already saw that but It did not work for me

Comment: The other feature I can think of is the IntelliCode whole line completions.  Is it showing the whole `public void OnAnimatorIK(int layerIndex) { }` in a greyed out text before you type the `(`?

Comment: yes it shows as a suggestion. But I want the suggestion in generell so I see what possible functions I could use.

Comment: I don't see a setting in VS to change the commit behavior for those suggestions, I would recommend using the Feedback tool in VS to suggest this feature.